# SAS surveymeans median

Tags: sas

I have a survery data set and would like to do a basic domain analysis. If I'm interested in the median of age. After using SAS codes:
     proc surveymeans data=survey mean median;
     domain population;
     weight weight;
     var age;
     run;

I got WARNING: Quantiles are not available for domain analysis.
Is there alternative for this ? I current using SAS 9.3 SAS/STAT9.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS doesn't permit explicit calculation of the quantiles (including Median) through SURVEYMEANS in SAS until SAS Analytics 13.1 (which is available with SAS 9.4).  See [this note](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_whatsnew_sect032.htm) for more information.

There are options for calculating it yourself; see for example [this thread](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Statistical-Procedures/Question-regarding-Surveymeans-and-Medians/td-p/105285).